# SOAP client with Ruby and Savon: How to add EncodingType attribute in Nonce element

Tags: ruby, web-services, soap-client, savon

I need to create a ruby web service client(with Savon) to make a soap call to a web service which requires the EncodingType in the Nonce.
So the correct soap message will have the Nonce element like this:

```
......
<wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">SomeHashValue</wsse:Nonce>
......
```

But in my Savon client, I don't know how to add that attribute in the Nonce element.
My code here:

```
......
client = Savon.client do
  wsdl.endpoint = "http://webservicehost/TestWebService"
  wsdl.namespace = "namespace"
  wsse.credentials "username", "password"
  wsse.digest = "true"
end
client.request :get_service do |soap|
  soap.input = [ 
    "GetService", 
    { "xmlns" => "namespace" } 
  ]
soap.body = {
    "locale" => "en_US",
    "serviceID" => '123'
  } 
end
......
```

and the Nonce in the generated SOAP message is like:

```
 ......
    <wsse:Nonce>SomeHashValue</wsse:Nonce>
 ......
```

So my question is, how to add the attribute EncodingType to the Nonce element, without changing/removing the SomeHashValue in the Nonce element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had success modifying the `gems\akami-1.2.1\lib\akami\wsse.rb` file's `def wsse_username_token` method.

I don't know the best way but this does work, merely add to the `:attributes!`.

Before:

```
:attributes! => { "wsse:Password" => { "Type" => PASSWORD_DIGEST_URI } }
```

After:

```
:attributes! => { "wsse:Password" => { "Type" => PASSWORD_DIGEST_URI }, "wsse:Nonce" => { "EncodingType" => 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary'} }
```